# Need help completing PHP function - return array of dates

Tags: php

I need to create a function for a project I'm working on:

Given 3 variables:

1. start date
2. array of days
3. # of dates to return

Return the dates

ie/

```
$start_date = "01-01-2011"
$days[] = [[Monday],[Wednesday],[Friday]]
$number_dates = 9
```

Should return:

```
$dates[] = [[03-01-2011],[05-01-2011],[07-01-2011],[10-01-2011],[12-01-2011],[14-01-2011],[17-01-2011],[19-01-2011],[21-01-2011]]
```

How can I achieve this the simplest way possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$start_date = "01-01-2011";
$days = array('Monday', 'Wednesday', 'Friday');
$number_dates = 9;

$result = getDates($start_date, $days, $number_dates);

echo "<pre>";echo var_dump($result);echo "</pre>";

function getDates($start_date, $days, $number_dates)  {
    $result = array();

    $startTime = mktime(0,0,0, (int)substr($start_date,4,2), (int)substr($start_date,0,2), (int)substr($start_date,6,4));

    if (count($days) > 0) {
        $n = 1;
        $t = $startTime;
        while ($n <= $number_dates) {
            $t += 24 * 3600;
            if (in_array(date('l', $t), $days)) {
                $result[] = date('d-m-Y', $t);
                $n++;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

result:

```
<pre>array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "03-01-2011"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "05-01-2011"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "07-01-2011"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "10-01-2011"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "12-01-2011"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "14-01-2011"
  [6]=>
  string(10) "17-01-2011"
  [7]=>
  string(10) "19-01-2011"
  [8]=>
  string(10) "21-01-2011"
}
</pre>
```

Comment: Perfect - exactly as required!! Thanks :)